# Accessing/ referencing external files in node-webkit application

Tags: node-webkit

I'm developing a node-webkit application that i want to distribute as an .exe file. However. I need to have dynamic content editable by the end user would i be able to link/ reference to external files and folders in my html/ css file using a relative path( maybe if i designate a particle folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A packed node-webkit application can identify its starting folder this way:

```
var appDir = require('path').dirname(process.execPath);
```